# Designing an angular based container

Tags: angular

Can anyone guide me in designing the core of a angular based platform?
The idea is to develop a core and distribute it so that other applications can be built on top of that.

The core should provide various hosting components that serve as containers. The core will provide various base components to develop custom components so that they can be loaded into the core host components.

For example the core will provide a host component (like window) and within that various other child items (components) can be loaded. These child components are the components defined and declared in the modules that have dependency over core.

I am having difficulty in understanding how the core is going to know about the child components,
How the core host component will look like,
How the communication between the host and the child components will be like.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is much too vague, and most probably not a practical way of approaching design. You generally don't start by building a foundation, out of the blue, for future applications. You write an application or two, then identify what the common services/classes/components they have, and extract them to start building a common foundation (if really needed). Especially if you don't even master angular yet. Do the simplest thing you can imagine, following the documentation. Only refactor and extract common functionality when needed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The idea is to build a platform to develop components and use the underlying data streaming architecture and other  basic components like Grid. I understand what you mean and appreciate your feedback but consider this as an extensible application.

Comment: When the router-outlet comes into play, you can picture it in your mind better. In our project we have a menu component and main component. The router-outlet is inside of main component. When the user clicks through menus, different module's components loads into main component.

Comment: I think I am I stuck at circular dependency between the core module and the client module. Client module has dependency over the core and can use it's components. But how do I tell the core about the client module at run time? I could use MEF container in C# to tell core about the client modules but how do I do that in angular? @JBNizet